# Regex cut last character from expression if it has more than 4 characters

Tags: regex, character, cut

I'm looking for a way to cut the last character from a expression if it has more than 4 characters using regex

e.g.

187
6
31673
9667
11857
07

after processing should look like:

187
6
3167
9667
1185
07

Comment: What should the result look like if the expression has 6 characters?

Comment: The result should have 4 characters.

Comment: It seems that you customize Visual Web Ripper with C# code. We don't know how you take in those numbers, though (in one string, or separate strings).

Comment: Thank you, that was a good point.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a regex instead of something like this?

```
var output = (input.Length <= 4) ? input : input.SubString(0, input.Length - 1);
```

If you have to use regular expressions this one should do the job.

```
^(.{0,4})$|^(.+)(?:.)$
```

Comment: Because I use software where I can put only regex content transformation script, I think.

Comment: Doesn't change anything, the output is identical as input.

Comment: Maybe your regex dialect does not support part of the expression?

Comment: I don't know, I use Visual Web Ripper software.

Comment: I have no clue what that would support.

Comment: I found, that the first part ^(.{0,4}) works fine but only for first line, it removes other lines.

Comment: Actually the first part ^(.{0,4}) works fine, I've made a mistake with testing at first.